# Activate Hearthstone season chest cards?

Tags: hearthstone

I played my first "season" in Hearthstone and the chest I got said that I got the card "Betrayal" which is a Rogue card.

Nevertheless, in my collection interface for Rogues, the card Betrayal does not show up.

Is there something special I have to do to collect or activate cards from my season chest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be a common bug.  Close Hearthstone and reopen it, and your golden Betrayal should then be in your collection.